# Repurposing allocated memory

Tags: c, glibc

I have a global array of strings with undefined lengths:

```
static char *array[1<<8];
```

Those strings will be replaced by other strings, with probably a different size.
Every time a new string comes in and needs to be stored in the array, I have to do this:

```
free(array[i]);
array[i] = malloc(len);
strcpy(array[i], str);
```

Now it could happen that the old and the new string are very similar in size, and memory could just be reused.
I believe that `realloc()` does reuse the allocated memory directly in such circumstances.

Is there a standard function like `realloc()` that does not copy the data?

Or does does it even mater performance wise, because of the `free()`/`malloc()` are somehow smart enough to reuse the memory of the latest `free()` directly if it fits?

I've found that. But the responses are not satisfying for me.
[Why is there no function in standard C library like realloc() without data copying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696006/why-is-there-no-function-in-standard-c-library-like-realloc-without-data-copyi)

Comment: Have you profiled your application and found that updating this global array is an actual performance bottleneck?  If your application isn't fast enough and you don't have actual evidence from accurate profiling that this is a performance bottleneck, optimizing this is worse than a waste of time:  you'd be taking presumable tested and bug-free code that's simple and easy to maintain and replacing it with more complex code that hasn't been tested and will be harder to maintain in the future.  That's worse thana waste of time.

Comment: There is no such thing in standard C. Maybe there are platform specific extensions. [Edit] and add your platform. But anyway the standard memory allocation functions are usually rather smart nowadays.

Comment: If the new allocation is really a performance problem you could check the size and allocate a new memory block only if the new string is too long for the existing block and maybe round up the new size a bit.

Comment: Avoiding malloc() is often enough a good increase of performance. If your code is called often, then I wouild rather use a second array (or a struct) tracking the length of the string, so you only have to realloc if it's needed. Using realloc should also help a bit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Thanks for your advise, I sometimes forget. I'm creating a high performance web server, and I try to avoid allocations, especially frequent ones.

Comment: Do you have a limit on the strings, or can they be of totally arbitray length? malloc/free are for general purpose. If you know your daa, you ight be better of with a custom memory management, tailored for your specific usecase.

Comment: @Devolus, that's what I'm going to do otherwise, but it is rather optimal, because `realloc()` might round up to 8 bytes and since glibc knows the size of the allocated memory anyway it feels like I'm building my own allocator on top of `malloc()`/`free()` which sounds stupid

Comment: @Devolus, most strings are about 1 to 16 characters in size, but a string could also get several MB in size.

Comment: If really most strings are only 16 bytes long, then I wouild preallocate for that length, and only do the special cases dynamically. But if this is effective or not depends on your actual distribution of lengths. Keeping the length of the strings in a second array, would definitly help. malloc/free are not THAT good for high performance use cases. I also increased performance on our webserver by writing a custom solution for memory managment.

Comment: Since this is glibc, do you know about [`malloc_usable_size()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)?

Comment: In `malloc(len);`, if `len` is the length of the string (as returned by `strlen`), that is not enough memory. You need `malloc(len+1);` to allow for the null terminator.

Comment: @Devolus I think, I'm gonna create a custom memory management, that only allocates and when the request ends the allocator will reset for the next request. Since `malloc()` and `free()` lead to memory fragmentation over time I might end up doing that anyway.

Comment: I find myself occasionally wishing for this, too, but I suspect that the bulk copying is a very small part of the runtime of `realloc`. If you do create a custom memory management, I would be interested to hear how it compares.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Before you reinvent the wheel, I suggest you at least take a look at the [Apache Portable Runtime (APR) nemory pool](http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/pools), which is an efficient memory management system optimised for session-oriented servers, and specifically the Apache web server. Even if you don't adopt the APR, it has lots of relevsnt good ideas.